# What's the difference between Spatial angular velocity and Body angular velocity?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In rigid body, Spatial angular velocity is defined by
$$\dot{R}(t)R^{-1}(t)$$

where $R$ is rotation matrix, and Body angular velocity
$$R^{-1}(t)\dot{R}(t)$$

Wow, it's some fuzzy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us suppose a rigid body $\mathcal{B}$ is undergoing a purely rotational motion. In this case, we say that its configuration space is the space of rotations in Euclidean three space, i.e., $SO(3)$.

Now, assume that $X \in \mathcal{B}$. An element $R \in SO(3)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by rotations. As a result, $x = RX \in R(\mathcal{B})$.

When the rigid body is in motion, the matrix $R$ is time-dependent and the velocity of a point on the body is $\dot{x} = \dot{R}X = \dot{R}R^{-1}x$. Since $R$ is an orthogonal matrix $R^{-1}\dot{R}$ and $\dot{R}R^{-1}$ are skew-symmetric matrices, and so we can write

\begin{equation}
  \dot{x} = \dot{R}R^{-1}x = \omega \times x,
\end{equation}

which defines the **spatial angular velocity vector** $\omega$. Thus, $\omega$ is given by *right translation* of $\dot{R}$ to the identity.

The corresponding **body angular velocity** is defined by $\Omega = R^{-1}\omega$, so that $\Omega$ is the angular velocity relative to a body fixed frame. Notice that

\begin{equation}
  R^{-1}\dot{R}X = R^{-1}\dot{R}R^{-1}x = R^{-1}(\omega \times x) = R^{-1}\omega \times R^{-1}x = \Omega \times X,
\end{equation}

so that $\Omega$ is given by *left translations* of $\dot{R}$ to the identity (to be precise to the tangent space of the identity element of the Lie group $SO(3)$).

The physical interpretation of this mathematical jargon is the following. We fix two coordinate frames, one to the earth, $\Sigma_E$, one to the body, $\Sigma_B$. This body is purely rotating with respect to the earth. While the **spatial angular velocity** of the rigid body is the expression of **the** angular velocity of the rigid body in the inertial frame $\Sigma_E$, the **body angular velocity** of the rigid body is its expression in the body-fixed frame $\Sigma_B$.

Reference: Marsden and Ratiu, *Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry*, Springer, 2013.

Comment: thank you! in physical, why body angular velocity isn't zero? assume we are live in body-fixed frame.

Comment: Because the angular velocity is not the zero vector, in general.

Think of this as expressing a vector in two different reference frames (bases). If the vector is not zero in one basis, it cannot be zero in another.

Comment: oh, i see, it's just the different expression in different frame.thank you!

Comment: @Aykut but the angular velocity vector will have constant direction in the body frame even if it doesn't have changing direction in the world frame right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "... even if it doesn't have changing direction in the world frame." There is a unique angular velocity of a rigid body. This is a vector quantity; and as such you can express this quantity in any reference frame you choose to consider. If for a period of time, say t in [t0, tf] the angular velocity is constant, then the body will be rotating about the unit vector along the angular velocity vector (i.e., the expression of this vector in *any* frame remain the same (as their corresponding expressions).